# Objective C: Function help

Tags: objective-c, function

Greetings,

I have the following function:

```
-(NSString*) nudgePhoneNumber:(NSString*)num{
    NSString *nudged=@"";
    [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
    [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s" withString:@""];
    [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
    [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
    //NSLog(nudged);
    return nudged;
}
```

And I'm calling it as follows:

```
-(IBAction) phoneNumberUp:(id)sender{
    NSString *mob=phoneNumber.text;
    NSString *result=@"";
    [result nudgePhoneNumber:mob];
        ...
}
```

But I keep getting an exception: "-[NSCFException nudgePhoneNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" and "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'"

I'm quite new to Objective-C and think I just need someone to have a quick look-over.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if both `nudgePhoneNumber:` and `phoneNumberUp:` are defined in the same class, then `phoneNumberUp:` should be more like this:

```
-(IBAction) phoneNumberUp:(id)sender{
    NSString *mob=phoneNumber.text;
    NSString *result=nil;
    result = [self nudgePhoneNumber:mob];
     ...
}
```

also, I think the `nudgePhoneNumber:` method isn't really doing anything. You might have to do it more like this:

```
-(NSString*) nudgePhoneNumber:(NSString*)num{
    NSString *nudged = num;
    nudged = [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
    nudged = [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s" withString:@""];
    nudged = [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    nudged = [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
    nudged = [nudged stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
    //NSLog(nudged);
    return nudged;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In which class is your method `-(NSString*) nudgePhoneNumber:(NSString*)num` being declared and implemented?

You're creating an NSString object on the line `NSString *result=@"";` and then you're trying to call the method using the NSString object. As NSString doesn't have a method called `nudgePhoneNumber:` you're getting an unrecognized selector runtime error (this exception is thrown when a *message is sent to an object that doesn't respond to that message* (key terminology there).

I suggest you take another look at how you "call methods" (really you're "sending a message") in Objective-C.

Comment: The method is in the same class. Should I use 'self'?

Comment: There is also the issue of using `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString` with an `NSString` instead of `NSMutableString`

Comment: If the method is in the same class, then you do use the keyword "self"! :)

Comment: Abizern has raised another issue to do with the immutable nature of NSString which you should also have a little look into by simply checking the documentation for the classes NSString and NSMutableString.